# Accessing environmental variable in Cypress test

Tags: cypress

I am trying to call an external script from a Cypress test using `cy.exec` to create an environmental variable which I then want to access this environmental variable in the test. Is this possible using `Cypress.env(<environmental variable>)`?

The external script looks like:

```
const cypress = require('cypress');
const pkg = require('@glib/cypress-secrets');

const { createAuthApiKeyKubeSecret } = pkg;
const username = 'test-consumer';    

const apikey = createAuthApiKeyKubeSecret(username);
console.log(apikey);
process.env.apikey = apikey;
```

This script is called by the before function in the test.

```
describe("Test to create a capability", function () {
    before(() => {
        cy.exec('node create-secret.js');
    });

    after(() => {
        cy.exec('node delete-secret.js', {log: true});
    });

    it('Checks on the Create page', function() {
        cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl + "?apikey=" + Cypress.env('apikey'));
        // We need to check if we are on the correct page
        // We just need to check two elements, a label and a button.
        cy.contains('About the capability').should('exist');
        cy.contains('button', 'Next Step').should('exist')
    });
});
```

The `baseUrl` is set correctly but the `apikey` environmental variable is coming back undefined.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-2-cypress-env-json)) you have to put cypress_ or CYPRESS_ before the variable name:

```
process.env.cypress_apikey = apikey;
```